# Installing the MySQLdb Python package

Tags: mysql, centos, python

I'm trying to install the MySQLdb Python package on my CentOS 5.1 machine, without success.

At first I tried using easy_install, but the version it installed was 1.2.1, which was too old for Django, which required 1.2.1p2 at the very least.

So I went to download the source from the [SourceForge project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/). I put the archive on my desktop and extracted to a folder there. Then I installed according to the instructions, with `setup.py build` and `setup.py install`. This seemed to work at first, but a perverse thing happened: It uses the folder on the desktop when working with the package! I know because I tried importing the package with Python, and it gave me some warning mentioning the path on my desktop!

What's going on here and what can I do?

(Note: The Python version installed here is 2.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, one needs to do `easy_install mysql-python` instead of `easy_install mysql_python`.

Comment: Good grief.  I had to look at your answer twice just to see the difference.  Glad you caught it.